# Construct infinitely many finite, undirected, connected, symmetric graphs of girth $k$?

Tags: graph-theory

For any given $k \geq 3$, is it possible to construct infinitely many finite, undirected, connected and symmetric (i.e. edge-transitive and vertex-transitive) graphs with girth $k$ ?

To clarify,

If $k = 3$, any complete graph with at least $3$ vertices satisfies this definition

If $k = 4$, any hypercube (of dimension $d \geq 2$) works

If $k = 5$, the dodecahedron and the Petersen graph work

If $k = 6$, Odd graphs $O_n$ work (with $n > 3$)

The cases $k \geq 8$ are treated in "Explicit construction of graphs with an arbitrary large girth and of large size" (1995) by Lazebnik and Ustirnenko

Can we construct, for each $k\in \{5,7\}$, infinitely many such examples ?

Comment: Take arbitrily many $k$-cycles. Or do you require the graphs to be connected?

Comment: Also, being edge- and vertex-transitive is strictly weaker than being symmetric. See the [Holt graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holt_graph).

Comment: yes, the graph must be connected

Comment: what is the definition of being symmetric then (this is not my field) ?
Because the first definition Google gives is this :
A symmetric graph is a graph that is both edge- and vertex-transitive (Holton and Sheehan 1993, p. 209)

Comment: The graph must also be undirected.

Comment: For $k=4$ [prism graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prism_graph) work. For $k=6$ [odd graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odd_graph) work.

Comment: Thanks for this @Servaes

Now, the cases $k = 5$ and $k \geq 7$ remain.

Comment: In "Explicit construction of graphs with an arbitrary large girth and of large size" (1995) by Lazebnik and Ustirnenko it is shown that for any girth there exist graphs which are both vertex-transitive and edge-transitve.

Comment: The cases k≥8 are treated in "Explicit construction of graphs with an arbitrary large girth and of large size" (1995) by Lazebnik and Ustirnenko, so the cases $k = 5$ and $k = 7$ remain